# Cannot navigate between tkinter frames. It shows Attribute error

Tags: python, object, oop, tkinter, attributeerror

I went through a couple of posts about navigation between tkinter frames but didn't find those useful. I am trying to create an app. I have a LogIn Page and Home Page. I want to navigate between these two frames on the click event of submit button in the LogIn Page. I have used two functions in the event of click of submit button. I have done database connection also.

When the program is executed, it shows the LogIn Page.After entering the details when I click the submit button it shows attribute error.

Following is the code I executed.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import messagebox


class App(tk.Tk):
    bg_img_path = "images\\bg9.png"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("1500x750")

        main_frame = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=50, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1,
                              background="#e6ffe6")
        main_frame.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='True')

        main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.bkgr_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=self.bg_img_path)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (LoginPage,HomePage):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(main_frame, self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(LoginPage)

    def show_frame(self, container):
        frame = self.frames[container]
        frame.tkraise()


class BasePage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)

        label_bkgr = tk.Label(self, image=controller.bkgr_image)
        label_bkgr.place(x=0, y=0)


class LoginPage(BasePage,tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent, controller)

        login_frame = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=50, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1,
                               background="#e6ffe6")
        login_frame.grid(row=400, column=20, padx=500, pady=250)

        self.label_title = tk.Label(login_frame, text="Log In", font=("Helvetica", 40), bg="#e6ffe6")
        self.label_title.grid(row=0, column=20, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.label_username = tk.Label(login_frame, text="Username", font=("Helvetica", 20), bg="#e6ffe6")
        self.label_username.grid(row=50, column=20, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.entry_username = tk.Entry(login_frame, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 20))
        self.entry_username.grid(row=50, column=30, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.label_password = tk.Label(login_frame, text="Password", font=("Helvetica", 20), bg="#e6ffe6")
        self.label_password.grid(row=60, column=20, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.entry_password = tk.Entry(login_frame, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 20))
        self.entry_password.grid(row=60, column=30, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.login_button = tk.Button(login_frame, text="Log In", command=lambda: [self.submit,App.show_frame(self,HomePage)], font=("Helvetica", 20),
                                      bg="#e6ffe6")
        self.login_button.grid(row=70, column=25, padx=10, pady=10)

    def submit(self):
        self.u_name = self.entry_username.get()
        self.p_word = self.entry_password.get()

        employee = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="edatabase")
        cursor_variable = employee.cursor()

        cursor_variable.execute("INSERT INTO login VALUES ('" + self.u_name + "','" + self.p_word + "')")
        employee.commit()

        employee.close()

        messagebox.showinfo("Log In", "Succesfull")


class HomePage(BasePage):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent, controller)

        label1 = ttk.Label(self, text='Home', font=("Helvetica", 20))
        label1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

The attribute error thrown is as follows:

```
C:\Users\write\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe "C:/Users/write/PycharmProjects/OOP trials/login_bg_img_trial2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\write\PycharmProjects\OOP trials\login_bg_img_trial2.py", line 97, in <module>
    app = App()
  File "C:\Users\write\PycharmProjects\OOP trials\login_bg_img_trial2.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.show_frame(LoginPage)
  File "C:\Users\write\PycharmProjects\OOP trials\login_bg_img_trial2.py", line 33, in show_frame
    frame = self.frames[container]
KeyError: <class '__main__.LoginPage'>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `class LoginPage(BasePage,tk.Frame):` turn into `class LoginPage(BasePage):`

Comment: @Atlas435 That isn't a good idea

Comment: Change `self.show_frame(LoginPage)` to `self.show_frame("LoginPage")`

Comment: @TheLizzard where is the point to keep it ?

Comment: @TheLizzard I tried your suggestion it shows the same error

Comment: @Atlas435 It isn't going to solve the problem.

Comment: @Atlas435 I tried your suggestion and now it shows key error                           
     __init__
    self.show_frame(LoginPage)
  File "C:\Users\write\PycharmProjects\OOP trials\login_bg_img_trial2.py", line 33, in show_frame
    frame = self.frames[container]
KeyError: <class '__main__.LoginPage'>

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @TheLizzard [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `App.__init__` change:

```py
self.show_frame(LoginPage)
```

to

```py
self.show_frame("LoginPage")
```

The dictionary that you have (`self.frames`) contains the frame name as the key and the frame instance as the value.

---

Also add `self.controller = controller` to `BasePage.__init__` so you can keep a reference to the `controller`.

That will allow you to change the

```py
self.login_button = tk.Button(..., command=lambda: [..., App.show_frame(self,HomePage)])
```

into:

```py
self.login_button = tk.Button(..., command=lambda: [..., self.controller.show_frame("HomePage")])
```

That should fix all of the problems

---

Please note that as @Atlas435 said you don't need the `tk.Frame` from the `class LoginPage(BasePage,tk.Frame)`. Also using a list inside a lambda to execute functions is unpythonic. It's easer to just define a new function.

Comment: Thanks the error is resolved. Now it's possible to navigate between frames. But the values entered while login is not recorded in the database. There is no error now. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ArchanaJalajaSurendran Change `command=lambda: [self.submit, ...]` to `command=lambda: [self.submit(), ...]`. (You forgot the brackets :D)

Comment: thanks a lot.. I really forgot about the ()